# Basemap npstere to cartopy NorthPolarStereo CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, basemap, pyproj, cartopy

Somebody has given me the following code to convert north-polar stereographic (x,y) coordinates to WGS84 (lon,lats):

```
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=0,resolution='l')
lon,lat = m(x,y,inverse=True)
```

Unfortunately I can't install Basemap as it's incompatible with several of the modules in my environment. So I'm trying to replicate the Basemap operation using pyproj, but I'm not sure how to generate the corresponding CRS objects using Cartopy.

I'm trying:

```
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer
import cartopy

WGS_Proj = 'EPSG:4326'

PS_Proj = cartopy.crs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0)

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(PS_Proj.proj4_init, WGS_Proj)
        
lat, lon = transformer.transform(x, y)
```

However when I try to construct the NorthPolarStereo coordinate reference system I'm able to give it the "lon_0" keyword from the basemap command (which corresponds to "central_longitude" in Cartopy-world, but not the "boundinglat=60" keyword, which has no analogue in Cartopy-world. So the code runs, but because I haven't specified the boundinglat, the result isn't correct.

How can I translate the basemap command to Cartopy?

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs.html ?

Comment: It seems relevant but I'm not sure how to use it to answer the question.